# Background-image moving partially out of window when specified with background-position: center;

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
</head>
<body>

<body>
```

My CSS code is as follows:

```
body {
    background-image: url(tree.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Now my google chrome browser shows the following output:

[image]

Here, the image tree is at top center and partially out of window.

To rectify this I change my CSS code to the following:

```
body {
        background-image: url(tree.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        margin-top: 600px;
    }
```

Now my browser shows the following output:

[image]

My question is why I have to add a margin at top and background-image is not by default going to center of my browser page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's related to the height of the document. Without content, the body height is  at it's minimum. If you change your CSS to the following, the background image should be central:

```
html {
    background-image: url(tree.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z85ony88/

Furthermore, if you need the background image on the body. Use the following:

```
html {
  height:100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because of your body doesn't have enough height to show full image. By setting height to your body, or having enough content on your body will solve the issue. Check below snippet. Here i set `height: 100vh` to cover the screen, check it on fullscreen view.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: @Sonevol it's Viewport height